# Xamarin.Forms Dependency Service UWP: methodNotFoundException

Tags: c#, service, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have a [Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) Portable project which targets Android, iOS, UWP and Windows10. I want to call specific platform code (UWP, Android, iOS, win10) from the Portable project. Googleing around it seems this can be done using [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/).
I am having some problems to call UWP code. Following the tutorial i have created an interface in the Portable project like so:

```
namespace PushClient
{
    public interface IWebSocket
    {

        void test();

    }
}
```

Then in the UWP project i have created a class implementing the interface:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PushClient.UWP.WebSocketUWP))]
namespace PushClient.UWP
{
    public class WebSocketUWP : IWebSocket
    {
        public WebSocketUWP() {}
        public void test() { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UWP TEST"); }

    }
}
```

Then in in the App.xaml.cs file in the UWP project i have registered the dependency as follows:

```
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {

#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif



            List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();


            assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(WebSocketUWP).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);


            Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<IWebSocket>();

// [...]

}
```

When i try to call the UWP test method from the shared code in Portable project like so

```
DependencyService.Get<IWebSocket>().test();
```

a methodNotFoundException is thrown. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit long after the question but the answer can perhaps still have any interest for someone..
In UWP you have to do the 2 registrations, one like other platforms with the assembly attribute, but also one other "manually" in app.xaml.cs.

In the code above, the faulty part is that the registration in app.xaml.cs in done for the Interface... this is not the interface that must be registered but the implementation class for UWP.

Perhaps this will save the day of someone, someday, somewhere on earth, or elsewhere, who knows...

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling with that issue and your answer saved my day.